# QGraphicsView additem() getting bigger

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a signal that triggers the following slot on QT:

```
void MainWindow::stream_frame_changed(bool change, const QImage& image)
{
    if (stream == true && change == true)
    {
        QPixmap aux = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
        item->setPixmap(aux);
        ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(item);
    }
}
```

The signal is emmited every 100 milliseconds. I am noticing that there is a memory leak, and it makes sense, because I am adding many items to the scene without ever deleting them.

I do not know how to delete the previous items. If i execute the clear() function, the window closes, so it is not an option apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating new items you must reuse the existing item:

***.cpp**

on constructor:

```
ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(item);
```

and

```
void MainWindow::stream_frame_changed(bool change, const QImage& image)
{
    if (stream == true && change == true)
    {
        QPixmap aux = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
        item->setPixmap(aux);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the item is not being added to the scene